# make: ** NO targets specififed and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: c, makefile, valgrind

I am following along with "Learn C the Hard way" and came to the chapter on installing Valgrind, following these exact instructions:

```
# 1) Download it (use wget if you don't have curl)
curl -O http://valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2

# use md5sum to make sure it matches the one on the site
md5sum valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2

# 2) Unpack it.
tar -xjvf valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2

# cd into the newly created directory
cd valgrind-3.6.1

# 3) configure it
./configure

# 4) make it
make

# 5) install it (need root)
sudo make install
```

at step #4 I get the error in the title:

```
make: ** NO targets specififed and no makefile found. Stop.
```

What is going on?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that your step #3 failed, and so you cannot continue to step #4 until you get it to work.  What errors did you get from step #3?

Comment: I got error: Valgrind requires glibc version 2.2 - 2.17

Comment: Have you tried installing `glibc` and then retrying from step #3 ?

Comment: If you are using Linux, you can (and should, actually) install Valgrind by using the package management tool, for example if you are using CentOS, you can run `yum install valgrind` as `root` to install it.

Comment: Perhaps that particular project doesn't use `make`... Maybe CMake or ANT or one of any number of alternative build systems...

Comment: Er, Ploutox, glibc is the system runtime library.  Any standard server or desktop Linux distribution won't even boot without it.  twalberg, it's clear from the instructions that this is an autoconf package, not cmake/ant/whatever.  Lee Duhem is right that the best way is to install the system package.  However, if you REALLY want to build your own I suggest you get the latest version from http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html (3.9.0).  3.6.1 is over 3 years old and won't work well on modern systems.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue depending on your computer it may be caused by a bug in the old version of valgrind that the book asks you to install my advice is to use

> sudo apt-get install valgrind

to get the latest and greatest version hopefully without that bug.

Answer (score 0):

Well is there a `makefile` present? This error is usually reported when there is no makefile present in the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac only:

I am following the same tutorial and I saw this error when running ./configure

```
 configure: error: Valgrind works on Darwin 9.x and 10.x (Mac OS X 10.5 and 10.6)
```

[Valgrind 3.10.1](http://valgrind.org/downloads/) (the latest as I write this) doesn't support Mac OS Yosemite yet either.

For now you can install the development version of Valgrind with:

```
brew install --HEAD valgrind
```

or maybe just keep hacking as I'm sure the writers of "Learn C the hard way" would want you too :)